# Проблемы с float для текста

Tags: html, css

Есть css

```
body{
background: url(img/img2.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.main{
background-color: #fff;
max-width: 70%;
margin: 100px auto;
}

.p1{
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 30px;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.p2{
margin: 10px 0 5px 10px;
font-size: 17px;
}

.border{
border: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.games{
margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

hr{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 20px 300px 0 0;
}

ul{
float: right;
}
```

Код страницы:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:/website/1.css" />
<title>Games</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="main">

<div class="text">
<p class="p1">BestGame</p>
<p class="p2">lalaalalall</p>
</div>

<div class="border"></div>

<div class="pages">

<div class="games">
<h2>World of Tanks</h2>
<img src="D:\123.jpg">
<ul>
<li>Жанр</li>
<li>ytn</li>
<li>da</li>
</ul>
<hr>
</div>

<div class="games">
<h2>World of Tanks</h2>
<img src="D:\123.jpg">
<hr>
</div>

<div class="games">
<h2>World of Tanks</h2>
<img src="D:\123.jpg">
<hr>
</div>

</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Нужно чтобы ul, был справа от картинки (не так как щас а в плотную и чтобы я мог margin'ом отодвинуть если что). Но не могу понять почему щас не хочет. Наверн я криворукий как всегда.

Comment: Так он и находится справа от картинки и прекрасно перемещается при помощи margin.

Comment: Всё верно, маргином я могу его передвигать. Но мне нужно, чтобы ul был справа от картинки (сейчас он не справа а снизу). float не помогает, либо я что-то не так делаю... https://imgur.com/a/AI7lbxX

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  width:100px;
}
ul {
  width:300px;
}
```

И у тебя картинки в разных блоках. Надо дать им display-inline хотя бы